# PyCharm Call Graph is always loading, how to fix it?

Tags: python, pycharm, profiler

My PyCharm is professional for 30 days trial, I profiled my code but can't show Call Graph, the option is grey, and the Call Graph is always loading, how can I fix it?[image: The grey option]

[image]

Comment: I have same problem :-/ It sucks because outptut in Statistics tab is only poorly readable.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug in the latest 2021.2 release. Try rolling back to 2021.1.3 as suggested here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49917

Comment: Fixed in 2022.3.1 w/ latest Python plug-in: 213.6461.79